# Historical SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Is there an table on oracle database where historical SQL queries executed by users are stored?

Tried with v$sql, v$sqlstats, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try `dba_hist_sqltext`; join it to `dba_hist_snapshot` for some more info.

```
select *
from dba_hist_sqltext t join dba_hist_snapshot s on t.dbid = t.dbid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `V$` views report what is currently cached in the SGA, therefore they are not reliable as an audit trail.

The details in the `DBA_HIST_` views (DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT, DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT, DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT etc) persist for longer as they are captured from their `v$` equivalents as part of the Automatic Workload Repository feature (AWR), so make sure you are licensed for it to avoid a surprise bill.